# Google SignIn + Facebook SignIn + Email SignIn different class

Tags: java, android, facebook, firebase, google-signin

I am confused. I am creating app with authentication using Firebase.

I already create working GoogleSignIn and Email/Password SignIn. But now I have a little bit trouble in two things:

```
/* Variable for create user using Google button */
/* ******************************************** */
/*                   FACEBOOK                   */
/* ******************************************** */

CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
LoginButton loginButton;

mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new 
FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
}
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = 
    FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>
        () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in 
                 user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                     //                            updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", 
                   task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication 
                  failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 //                            updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

1. I am not sure how to properly create Facebook authentication, cuz I cannot after using it change activity to maps, like it works in GoogleSignIn. Here is my SignIn Activity.
2. The second question is connect with clean code. Right now whole this class look really terrible in my opinion, and I am sure it looks like that because I am a beginner. In this way I just wonder is it possible to create 3 diffrent for specific type of signIn (in this example FacebookLogin.class, GoogleLogin.class, EmailLogin.class and use this methods in one main activity which combines whole this in one ? I am not sure but is this call "inheritance" or should I use "Interface" to achieve that ?

Here is my main class with whole functions:

http://wklej.org/id/3291802/

Thanks for all answers :)

Comment: Take a look at Firebase Android authentication example at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. But it doesnt answer for my question about three different class, Is it possible for anyone to show me example of implementation 3 different class for SignIn and connection with one Main class which show this buttons etc.

Comment: You should consider using FirebaseUI for this. You will have to write just a few lines of code and you can easily integrate Google, Facebook and Email login in your app.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android